# How to create new folder named dd.MM.yyyy with ant?

Tags: ant

My ant script needs to create a folder that is named
with actual datetime and datetimepattern dd.MM.yyyy

Answer (score 2):

Use [tstamp](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tstamp.html) and [mkdir](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/mkdir.html) task like that :

```
<project>

<tstamp>
 <format property="datetime" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"/>
 </tstamp>

 <mkdir dir="C:/whatever/${datetime}">

</project>
```